# VBA Power Point Missing Reference Library

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I inherited the below macro someone wrote in Powerpoint and it is filled with code I don't quit understand. I am getting an error on the `For Each` line and am wondering if the reason is that I am missing a reference library that needs to be checked. Unfortunately, I cannot get ahold of the creator so I am just wondering if there is a certain reference I need activated to get ahold of the `WebResponse` properties

```
Dim versaries As WebResponse
Dim versary As Object

Set versaries = New WebResponse
Set versaries.Data = WebHelpers.ParseJson(ReadTextFile())

    For Each versary In versaries.Data   '<--- ERROR LINE
        '......
    Next versary
```

> Run-time error '438':
> Object doesn't support this property or method

**The only references currently activated on PP VBA Editor are**

1. Visual Basic For Applications
2. Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library
3. OLE Automation
4. Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: So it's not something that's available in the stock reference catalogue? Jeez, what in the world did I inherit